# DSF BFS and A* search task with 8balls implementation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am trying to solve task using dfs, bfs and A* search and currently I am totally stack. The task is following:
there are 4 black and 4 white balls which organized one by one black, white,black, white and so on. ALso there are 2 empty places in line. The balls need to be rearranged to get in result 4 black and 4 white in line. Only 2 balls which located togather can be moved. For example, imagine 1 - black ball, 0 - white ball

1 0 1 0 _ _ 1 0 1 0

1 0 1 0 0 1 1 - - 0

_ _ 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0

I cant imagine and build graph in my head, any advice is really appreciated

Comment: If you are asking a theoretical question (i.e. given this problem how can I represent it as a graph) then you have asked on the wrong site, use computerscience.SE.  If you cannot write a program to implement those algorithms, well SO isn't a code writing service. There's plenty of material and also python implementations out there, look at those and when you have tried something open a question *containing your code* and asking about a specific trouble you are having with the code.

Comment: This said: usually problems like this are easy to represent as graphs. Each node is a configuration and you have an edge between two configurations if you can go from one to the other using the moves allowed. The DFS/BFS/A* search then finds the (shortest) path between two configurations which represent the (shortest) sequence of allowable moves that provides a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration as you described it defines a state. You can consider each state a vertex in your graph. You have an edge between two states is there's a simple move that you can apply to the first state to reach the second state. This is your graph.

Now looking for a solution means finding a path between the vertices corresponding to the initial state and the desired state, and you can apply DFS, BFS, A* or whatever graph algorithm you would like.

Answer (score 0):

I write the following code in Java. There are 2 state "black, white and empty". Also I described and added lines where balls located. I assume it will work on DFS principle. Can somebody advise am I right& Does code follow DFS?

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DepthFirstSearch {

    private List<Vertex> vertexList = new ArrayList<Vertex>(10);

    private Vertex v1 = Vertex.build(1, State.BLACK);
    private Vertex v2 = Vertex.build(2, State.WHITE);
    private Vertex v3 = Vertex.build(3, State.BLACK);
    private Vertex v4 = Vertex.build(4, State.WHITE);
    private Vertex v5 = Vertex.build(5, State.EMPTY);
    private Vertex v6 = Vertex.build(6, State.EMPTY);
    private Vertex v7 = Vertex.build(7, State.BLACK);
    private Vertex v8 = Vertex.build(8, State.WHITE);
    private Vertex v9 = Vertex.build(9, State.BLACK);
    private Vertex v10 = Vertex.build(10, State.WHITE);

    public DepthFirstSearch() {
        v2.setParentVertex(v1);
        v3.setParentVertex(v2);
        v4.setParentVertex(v3);
        v5.setParentVertex(v4);
        v6.setParentVertex(v5);
        v7.setParentVertex(v6);
        v8.setParentVertex(v7);
        v9.setParentVertex(v8);
        v10.setParentVertex(v9);

        v1.setChildVertex(v2);
        v2.setChildVertex(v3);
        v3.setChildVertex(v4);
        v4.setChildVertex(v5);
        v5.setChildVertex(v6);
        v6.setChildVertex(v7);
        v7.setChildVertex(v8);
        v8.setChildVertex(v9);
        v9.setChildVertex(v10);

        vertexList.add(v1);
        vertexList.add(v2);
        vertexList.add(v3);
        vertexList.add(v4);
        vertexList.add(v5);
        vertexList.add(v6);
        vertexList.add(v7);
        vertexList.add(v8);
        vertexList.add(v9);
        vertexList.add(v10);
    }

    private void run() {
        printVertex(v1);

        while (!isFinalResult()) {
            search(v1);
        }
    }

    private void search(Vertex vertex) {
        if (isFirstEmpty(vertex)) {
            State prevState = vertex.getParentVertex().getState();
            Vertex mVertex = null;

            for (Vertex v : vertexList) {
                if (hasPrevState(v, prevState)) {
                    mVertex = v;
                    break;
                }
            }

            State pState = mVertex.getState();
            State cState = mVertex.getChildVertex().getState();

            mVertex.setState(vertex.getState());
            mVertex.getChildVertex().setState(vertex.getChildVertex().getState());

            vertex.setState(pState);
            vertex.getChildVertex().setState(cState);

            findFinal(v1);

            System.out.println("=========================");
            printVertex(v1);
        } else {
            search(vertex.getChildVertex());
        }
    }

    private boolean isFirstEmpty(Vertex vertex) {
        return vertex.getState() == State.EMPTY && vertex.getChildVertex().getState() == State.EMPTY;
    }

    private boolean hasPrevState(Vertex vertex, State state) {
        return !vertex.isFinal() && vertex.getState() == state && vertex.getChildVertex().getState() != State.EMPTY;
    }

    private void findFinal(Vertex vertex) {
        final Vertex childVertex = vertex.getChildVertex();
        if (vertex.isFinal()) {
            findFinal(vertex.getChildVertex());
        } else if (vertex.getState() == State.BLACK && childVertex != null && childVertex.getState() == State.BLACK) {
            vertex.setFinal(true);
            findFinal(vertex.getChildVertex());
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    private void printVertex(Vertex vertex) {
        if (vertex != null) {
            System.out.println(vertex);
            printVertex(vertex.getChildVertex());
        }
    }

    private boolean isFinalResult() {
        boolean bResult = v1.getState() == State.BLACK;
        bResult &= v2.getState() == State.BLACK;
        bResult &= v3.getState() == State.BLACK;
        bResult &= v4.getState() == State.BLACK;
        bResult &= v5.getState() == State.WHITE;
        bResult &= v6.getState() == State.WHITE;
        bResult &= v7.getState() == State.WHITE;
        bResult &= v8.getState() == State.WHITE;
        return bResult;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DepthFirstSearch search = new DepthFirstSearch();
        search.run();
    }
}
```